# Grails' Config.groovy in plugins and dependent apps

Tags: grails, groovy, configuration, grails-plugin

I am making both a Grails plugin and several Grails apps that will use the plugin.

I want to define a few properties and give them defaults in the plugin, but allow apps to override their values (optional). This question surrounds the mechanical details of how to wire both plugin and child app alike in this manner.

Say I want my plugin (`grails-myplugin`) to define the following properties in its `Config.groovy`:

```
myplugin {
    fizz {
        whistles = true  // Default for all child apps using this plugin
        buzz = 3         // Default for all child apps using this plugin
    }
}

grails.plugins.anotherPlugin.widget = 'auto'
grails.plugins.anotherPlugin.foo = '${myplugin.fizz.buzz}-40'  // Hence, by default, is '3-40'
```

Now, I would like a child Grails app, say, `myapp.war` (which uses `grails-myplugin`) to override the 2 `fizz` properties:

```
// myapp's Config.groovy:
myplugin {
    fizz {
        // whistles property not defined here so this app uses the
        // plugin's default of "true"

        // Overrides the plugin's value of 3; this imples
        // grails.plugins.somePlugin.foo is '12-40'
        buzz = 12
    }
}
```

A few issues here:

1. Have I placed everything correctly for the desired functionality?
2. With the above configuration, in `grails-myplugin`'s `Config.groovy`, I have an error message:

   > Multiple markers at this line: - The type groovy.lang.MetaClass cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.  - The type groovy.lang.GroovyObject cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

The fact that I'm getting this error tells me that I'm ether trying to do something that is impossible in Grails, or that I'm just doing it wrong. Ideas?

Comment: The Spring Security plugin might be a good example to look at. See the [`mergeConfig()`](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/java/grails/plugin/springsecurity/SpringSecurityUtils.java#L682) method

Answer (score 0):

Here you have how the quartz plugin resolved it:
https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-quartz/blob/master/QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy
Take a look at loadQuartzConfig method.

Also be aware that grails plugin exclude some parts of it to avoid problems when installing. It's configured on the plugin file like this:

```
def pluginExcludes = [
        'grails-app/jobs/**',
        'src/docs/**',
        'web-app/**'
    ]
```